# Spring boot application not recognizing spring taglib

Tags: spring-boot

I just started working on spring boot. using spring tool suite I have created one project. I started implementing internationalization concept by creating different messages_*.properties files.

But I am facing the below issue when try to access the jsp after running the application

```
2019-09-05 09:20:25.171 ERROR 2720 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].   [dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [The absolute uri: [http://www.springframework.org/tags] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application] with root cause

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: [http://www.springframework.org/tags] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:55) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:294) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:81) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTldResourcePath(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:251) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:122) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:431) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:489) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1445) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:144) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:244) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:105) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:385) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:362) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:346) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:603) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:170) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1371) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1056) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at com.tut.filter.SimpleFilter.doFilter(SimpleFilter.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.tut</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-tut-admin</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>spring-boot-admin</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <project.build.sorceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sorceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Configuration file

```
@Configuration
public class MVCConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
//Below method is to avoid CORS
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {

    registry.addMapping("/fileupload").allowedOrigins("");
    registry.addMapping("/multiplefiles").allowedOrigins("");
    registry.addMapping("/register").allowedOrigins("");
    WebMvcConfigurer.super.addCorsMappings(registry);
}

//Below three methods are for internationalization
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
   SessionLocaleResolver sessionLocaleResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
   sessionLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
   return sessionLocaleResolver;
}

@Bean
public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
    LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
    return localeChangeInterceptor;
}

@Bean(name = "messageSource")
public MessageSource getMessageResource()  {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageResource= new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();

    messageResource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
    messageResource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageResource;
}

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {

    registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor()); 
}
```

}

Controller class

```
@Controller
public class AdminController {

@Autowired
AdminDao dao;

@RequestMapping(value = { "/" })
public String homePage() {
    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method  = RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute Register register) {

    String userId  = register.getUserId();

    String pwd =  register.getPwd();

    boolean b = dao.login(userId, pwd);

    if(b) {

        return "admin";

    } else {

        model.addAttribute("msg", "Invalid Username/Password");

        return "redirect:/";
    }

}
}
```

Jsp page I have given the taglib and its usage like below

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <h1><spring:message code="welcome.text" text="default"/></h1>

<br><br>
<form action="/login" method="post">
<table>
<tr><th>User-Id</th><td> <input name="userId" id = "userId"></td></tr>
<tr><th>Password</th><td> <input type = "password" name="pwd"></td></tr>
<tr><th ><input type="submit" value="Login"/></th><th><a href="/register">Register</a></tr>
</table> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:derby:D:/Users/raja.gotluru/MyDB;create=true;create=true;
 spring.datasource.username=raja
 spring.datasource.password=raja
 spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
 spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
 spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

[image: Project-Strucutre]

Basing on the above pom.xml, maven loaded spring-webmvc jar in that under META-INF I am able to see spring.tld. But still I am getting this error.

Do I have to configure the taglib anywhere. If I remove the taglib tag and spring:message tag I am able to access the login page but I will not get the i18n mesage

Comment: Why do you need `<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>` in spring-boot ?

Comment: if I have to execute the below line then I require that taglib

    <h1><spring:message code="welcome.text" text="default"/></h1>

Comment: You can do it with `<th:>` tag in spring-boot !

Comment: Post your complete html and that controller class please

Comment: Its a jsp file not html. I have added the Jsp file and controller class to the question

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your project structure? And also your `application.properties `?

Comment: 1. JSP only work with WAR files, you are creating a JAR, switch the packaging to `war`. 2. you are mixing jars from different versions. Remove the `version` tag for the `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` dependency,.

Comment: You are mixing versions of Spring Boot. Do not do this.

Comment: Add `<packaging>war</packaging>` after `<version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>` as **M.Deinum** said and remove version from thymeleaf.

Comment: At present I am directly running the project in STS, I don't think it will have any issue with maven pom file. I tried with the two suggestions you have given but same issue.

Comment: @raajaag Can you try adding `<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>` thins dependency?

Comment: @raajaag Have you checked ?

Comment: Yes Avijit. But no luck